# Building Electron MEAN stack APP which gets data from local MetaTrader 4 Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, metatrader4, metatrader5

I'm building desktop **MEAN** ( **M**ongoDB **E**xpress **A**ngular **N**odeJS ) stack app, but I need to have an access to real time ( update on detected change ) currency exchange rates. In Excel, I can get a rate from MT4 easily with just 1 line code inside a cell, **if** `MT4.exe` **is runing**.

What I want is to somehow access the data with javascript, for example the EUR/USD rate.

Is it possible or does it need any 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

- https://github.com/PenguinTraders/MT4-Node.js

From the docs: "This demonstrates how you can communicate between a Node.js server and a MT4 client application quickly. There are no delays and the connection/calculations are done on the same tick."

Answer (score 1):

### In case a running `MT4.exe` process is allowed:

The forward-looking solution may use ZeroMQ messaging framework ( both NodeJS and MQL4 ports/wrappers exist ).

> **1)** Using a **`http`**-wrapped JSON is way "too"-expensive in real-time FX-events  processing.
> **2)** Using a **`ZeroMQ`**-framework allows one to integrate against a remote (M+N)-shaded fault-resilient group of processors ( performance scaling / load-balancing + a fail-safe distributed system )

---

## In case a running `MT4.exe` process in NOT allowed at all:

This scenario tests gray zone of legal protection of the MetaQuotes' intellectual property. Technically one can open and read a **`telnet <MT4server>:443`** and experiment with a stream of **`QUOTE`** messages incoming, but beware this may cause some legal countermeasures from MetaQuotes, and the history has shown a few of 'em. So, you have been warned.

Comment: I just need 8 currency exchange rates nothing more and the app is for personal use, not for selling or anything else.

Comment: **"just" 8?** Well, this makes your scenario more vulnerable to method 1) which uses synchronous / blocking mode of operations. Distributed concurrent processing is a must even for a single currency AI/ML models, where RTT-s between MT4 and ML-predictors are well under 80 ms, but FX-market cadence of events is anywhere between 1..15 ms, so **a non-blocking pipeline of concurrent processes is a must just for the first currency, if a serious processing of FX-market events is expected.**